# Making a button copy a text

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the "COPY ADDRESS" button copy a text I specify. I already tried to do it myself, but couldn't do it. It is very simple, I just have minimal knowledge.

http://porcelaincoins.com

```html
 <a class="btn btn-lg" href="#">copy address</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: _"It is very simple"_ - I would recommend that, as you have little knowledge, try not to say sentences like this. It will be very likely that you are wrong. -- Trust me, I know.

Comment: @porcelaincoins What is your exact desired results? You want the users to copy text to clipboard or to a certain HTML element? Either way, I would say javascript will be a must. Making a button called copy will not do copying by itself. If you have minimal knowledge, consider it as a chance to learn more then. Dive yourself into w3school tutorial to learn more basic concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will copy the text `abc` to the clipboard.

```js
function copy(text) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<div id=\"copy\" contenteditable>"+text+"</div>")
  document.getElementById("copy").focus();
  document.execCommand("selectAll");
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.getElementById("copy").remove();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copy('abc')">Copy</button>
```

### How does it work?

- Firstly, it makes a `contenteditable` div with the id of `copy` (don't use this ID anywhere else on your page). `contenteditable` elements are elements which are designed to be edited by the user, and there is extensive native JavaScript around them in the form of `document.execCommand` provided to help people make rich text editors. Part of `document.execCommand` is a `copy` method, to add text to the clipboard - however this only works reliably with selected text in a `contenteditable` element.
- The next step is for the code to *focus* on the div. This is as if the user had clicked on it - inputs are known as *focused* when they are active - for example the focused element in a form will receive the keyboard events
- The code then uses `document.execCommand` to select all of the text inside of the `contenteditable` div. In the first step, we ensured that this text was the text passed to the function.
- Then, it copies that content to the clipboard using `document.execCommand("copy")`. This is actually surprisingly simple.
- Finally, it removes the div from the DOM (i.e. destroys the div)

These actions should all happen so fast that the user will not realise that a div has even been created, however the text will appear on their clipboard.

Comment: where should the function go? and how do I integrate your solution of the button to my existing one

Comment: @porcelaincoins Make a `<script>` tag and closing `</script>` tag in-between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags of your webpage, and copy and paste the function in there. Then, just use `<button onclick="copy('abc')">Copy</button>` whenever you need to copy something, replacing `abc` with what you want to copy